# Spring Cloud Gateway Matching Routes with Path Variables and Custom Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to use the Sprign-Cloud-Gateway to implement role-based-authentication for an application with multiple microservices. I have 3 roles in the application: Customer, Deliverer and Dispatcher and I have a service called customer-authentication-service for creating & managing the JWTs and roles.

This is what I need to do, but could not do:

1. Create a Map of paths that maps the request method and url pattern to the list of roles that can access this url, such as:

   ```
       private final Map<Request, ImmutableList<String>> PERMISSIONED_ENDPOINTS = new HashMap<>(){{
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.PUT, "/*/collected/deliverer/*"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER"));
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.PUT, "/*/deposited/deliverer/*/box/*"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER"));
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.PUT, "/user/*/delivered/box/*"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER"));

           put(new Request(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer/{customerId}/status/delivered"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER", "CUSTOMER")); // Only the customer with that id
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer/{customerId}/status/active"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER", "CUSTOMER")); // Only the customer with that id

           put(new Request(HttpMethod.POST, "/boxes"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER", "CUSTOMER));
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.PUT, "/boxes/{boxId}"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER"));
           put(new Request(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/boxes/{boxId}"), ImmutableList.of("DISPATCHER"));
   }};
   ```
2. Match an incoming request that contains path variables with one of these patterns. I need to match complex paths such as: `/{deliveryId}/deposited/deliverer/{delivererId}/box/{boxId}`

   I couldn't understand how to match these.
3. Send a request to the customer-authentication-service to post the JWT and get the role so that I can check if it is allowed to see the url.

My question:

How should I implement the URL matching and applying custom logic (sending requests to get the role and checking it) with the complex urls that contain path variables. Should I store Pattern objects and compare the incoming request with these, using regexes?

I also checked Predicates and gone through all the docs but couldn't figure out how to implement it exactly. Please provide me with a minimal working example for one of the complex urls and I will figure out the rest.

Something like antMatchers in Spring Security would do the job but I am not sure if adding Spring Security is what I need in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not understand your question fully. I'll try to answer on the basic of whatever I understand.

What I think is you are looking of HTTP Request Interceptor, which will intercept your every request and then you can check if that URL matches to your desired URL.

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) is link to docs of HandlerInterceptor Interface. You can implement HandlerInterceptor and use preHandle() method where you will get access to incoming request.

Comment: I know about this but since my question is about Gateway, it already intercepts the requests and allows for applying a filter. My actual question is how can I match the urls with varying path variable parts so that I can map them to roles.